# how do I edit specifc part of text file in c?

Tags: c

> I wanna edit a specific part of text file but i don't know how i do this in c

I wanna do look like this:

```
Banana = 1 
Apple = 2
Orange = 3
```

and I wanna switch the Value os the fruits just the values

any ideias?

Comment: Are the new values going to be single-digit numbers or could some of them be multi-digit numbers?  If they remain single-digit numbers, you can make the change in situ.  If they become multi-digit numbers, then you have to work much harder to expand the file.  Shrinking is also hard work, though not as bad as expanding it.

Comment: Do you need to edit the file in-place? If not, just read the file line by line, and for each line parse the old values, make your changes, and output the changed line to another file. At the end you can move the new file over the original, if you prefer.